# Explicit implementation of properties

Tags: c#, interface, member-hiding

What i want to achieve is simple, i have an Interface `IDatasource`, which has a property called `DatasourceSettings`

```
public interface IDatasource
{
    DatasourceSettings DatasourceSettings { get; set; }
}
```

The implementing Class looks like this

```
public class TestDatasource : IDatasource
{
    public DatasourceSettings IDatasource.DatasourceSettings { get { return DatasourceSettings; } set { DatasourceSettings = (TestDatasourceSettings)value; } }
    public TestDatasourceSettings DatasourceSettings { get; set; }
}
```

As you may possibly see, the property is first implemented explicit, and it should return the `DatasourceSettings` Property of the class itself

So on, here is what i want to achieve

```
var ds = new TestDatasource();

if (ds.DatasourceSettings is TestDatasourceSettings && 
    ((IDatasource)ds).DatasourceSettings is DatasourceSettings)
{
    // should be true
}
```

The Error i get :

```
The modifier 'public' is not valid for this item
```

**So What's wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `public` from

```
public DatasourceSettings IDatasource.DatasourceSettings
```

Because it is explicitly implementing an interface method it is a-priori public

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class TestDatasource : IDatasource
    {
        DatasourceSettings IDatasource.DatasourceSettings { get { return DatasourceSettings; } set { DatasourceSettings = (TestDatasourceSettings)value; } }
        public TestDatasourceSettings DatasourceSettings { get; set; }
    }
```

Had the same mistake recently... turns out if the implementation is explicit you don't write access modifier.